# CEL Code Issues - Google Workspace Context-Aware

Tags: security, google-workspace, common-expression-language

I am currently attempting to create a Context-Aware security rule in **Google Workspace** that would potentially block users from accessing Google apps if they are under iOS version 15.0.0. I would like to achieve this using CEL (common expressive language).

In Google Context-Aware, here is what the Basic set-up would look like without code:

Allow access to apps or apply rule if a user:
Meets all attributes (AND)

Device OS: iOS
iOS version is 15.0.0 (in the format of MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH)

So for my CEL code snippet I currently have:
device.os == "iOS" && device.os_version <= "15.0.0"

However I receive this error:
undefined field 'os'

Anyone know what may be up or why this may be happening? Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the CEL code that you can use for the condition that you want to set on your Context-Aware Access in the Google Workspace Admin console to block users in accessing their Google Workspace apps if they are under iOS version 15.0.0.

**device.os_type == OsType.IOS && device.versionAtLeast("15.0.0")**

Reference:

[Custom access level specification](https://cloud.google.com/access-context-manager/docs/custom-access-level-spec?sjid=9284078960675139324-AP)

Comment: Please refrain from asking for upvotes and 'accepts' in comments and answers.